# Optimizing disk space when using Selenium Chrome Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The problem is that each profile takes up quite a bit of space. Are there any ways to reduce the space required?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBhzV.jpg)

My script creates user profiles and saves them to disk:

```
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disk-cache-size=0")
options.add_argument("--media-cache-size=0")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu-shader-disk-cache")
options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={profile_directory}")
```

Comment: Yes, I know it's Chrome that creates the folders and data. But maybe there is a way to disable something unnecessary in the webdriver, or with a script to delete some of the unnecessary folders or data every time. 
For example, pncal or component_crx_cache folders?